# Check availability right on flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's assume I am working on an online shop with high traffic. The items on sale are in high demand but also very limited. I need to make sure they won't be oversold.

Currently I have something like this:

```
$order->addProduct($product);
$em->persist($order);
if($productManager->isAvailable($product)){
    $em->flush();
}
```

However, I suppose this still allows for overselling a product if two orders come in within a very short period of time. What other possibilities are there to make sure the product will definitely never be oversold?

Comment: I think you should use the transactions ( a kind of transact sql but with docttrine ). You'll find doc here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html , because it's hard to explain easily (for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [pessimistic lock](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#pessimistic-locking) inside a transaction.

Let's say your `Product` entity has a `count` field containing the number of items left. After a user purchases an item, you decrease that field.

In this case you need a *pessimistic write lock*. Basically, it locks a row from being read and/or updated by other processes *that try to acquire a pessimistic lock too*. Those processes stay locked until the transaction that locked the row ends by either committing or rolling back or after a timeout.

So, you start a transaction, acquire a lock, check whether there are enough items left, add them to the order, decrease the number of items and commit the transaction:

```
$em->beginTransaction();

try {
    $em->lock($product, LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

    if ($product->getCount() < $numberOfItemsBeingPurchased) {
        throw new NotEnoughItemsLeftInStock;
    }

    $order->addItem($product, $numberOfItemsBeingPurchased);
    $product->decreaseCount($numberOfItemsBeingPurchased);

    $em->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $em->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

I'm suggesting throwing an exception here because 2 users buying the last item at the same time is an exceptional situation. Of course, you should use some sort of item count check — validation constraints or something else — *before* you run this code. So, if a user has made past that check but another user bought the last item *after* the check and *before* the current user actually bought it, it's an exceptional situation.

Also note that you should start and end transactions during a *single* HTTP request. I mean, do *not* lock a row in one HTTP request, wait for the user to complete the purchase and release the lock only after that. If you want users to be able to keep items in their carts for some time — like in the real world carts — use other means for that like reserving a product for the user for some time by still decreasing the count of items left in stock and releasing it if after some timeout by adding that number of items back.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this as the correct answer as it helped me understand pessimistic locking and it works for my question stated above. As my real case is a bit more complex I should be able to keep going from here.

Answer (score -1):

There's a complete chapter on `Doctrine2` talking about concurrency which is exactly what you need.

You need to wirte a transactionnal custom query, and lock down your table during the query time. It's all explained here : [Transactions and Concurrency](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html)

Comment: Thanks. I read the chapter but I am still a bit confused. Would you mind pointing me to the approach described there which fits my need?

Comment: Plus: I'd prefer not to lock the whole table as I don't mind people buying different products in the meantime.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't go any further than that as I never encounter this problematic.

Comment: downvote ? Really ? Stating the theory now worth a downvote on stackoverflow. wow